# Scaling probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I've been asked to calculate the probability for there to be less than two dots on a $\frac{1}{2}m^2$. With the average being 10 dots per $m^2$.
I assumed that due to the discrete nature of the question, the distribution we need to use is a Poisson Distribution.
That would give me $P(x \leq 2) = \sum_{0}^2 \frac{10^x e^{-10}}{x!} = 0.002769$ 
Now how would I use that to get the probability of getting two dots on half that size?

Comment: If the average number of dots on a region of area $1m^2$ is $10$, what is the average number of dots on a region of area $0.5m^2$?

Comment: @KennyWong would that be 5?

Comment: Yes. Now can you apply the Poisson distribution again?

Comment: I mean, do you intuitively think that it is valid to apply the Poisson distribution to the area of size $\frac 1 2 m^2$?

Comment: I might be thinking about it wrong. That's probably be why I'm this confused.

Comment: Well I guess applying it to $\frac{1}{2}m^2$ would be the same as applying it to $1m^2$. just the average would change to 5

Comment: Yes! That's all.